# Cannot write the full buffer with WriteFile function

Tags: c, winapi, writefile

I am trying to use `WriteFile` to write a simple text in a .TXT file. Here's my declaration:

```
// For WriteFile fuction
    BOOL writeFile;
    LPCVOID textToWrite = L"SakyLabs: Hello, MDE.";
    DWORD numberOfBytes = (DWORD)wcslen(textToWrite);
    DWORD numberOfBytesWritten;
```

`numberOfBytes` was based on Microsoft's example [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/opening-a-file-for-reading-or-writing).

Next, the WriteFile function:

```
writeFile = WriteFile(createFile, textToWrite, numberOfBytes, &numberOfBytesWritten, NULL);
```

I am getting createFile from a previous `CreateFileW` call. Also, I am using Unicode functions.

`WriteFile` works, but I only get this part of the text written in the file:

```
S a k y L a b s :   H
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `wcslen` doesn't return a number of bytes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a wide-charecter string `L"..."`. Each `WCHAR` is two bytes long -- because Windows is using UTF-16 for wide strings. `wcslen` counts the number `WCHAR` elements in it rather than bytes.

Either multiply the string length by the size of a `WCHAR`:

```
DWORD numberOfBytes = (DWORD)wcslen(textToWrite)*sizeof(WCHAR);
```

or use narrow char strings (preferably UTF-8 encoded if you actually use non-ASCII):

```
LPCVOID textToWrite = "SakyLabs: Hello, MDE.";
DWORD numberOfBytes = (DWORD)strlen(textToWrite);
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried changing the encoding in VS, but it did not work. It might be my fault. However, the multiply way worked.

Comment: If you write UTF-16 to a .txt file you should write a BOM at the start so other programs can identify the encoding.

Comment: FYI, neither code example should compile, as neither `wcslen()` nor `strlen()` take `LPCVOID` as input. Just because `WriteFile()` takes `LPCVOID`doesn't mean your variables should be declared as `LPCVOID`. All pointer types are implicitly convertible to `LPCVOID`. Use proper types for variables, eg `LP(C)STR` aka `(const) char*` for narrow strings, and  `LP(C)WSTR` aka `(const) wchar_t*` for wide strings.

Comment: @RemyLebeau [C allows implicit conversion to/from void*](https://godbolt.org/z/T5n7Y5jq5). While I agree with you that one shouldn't use a `void*` in this code just because `WriteFile` does, I prefer to to limit my answers in scope with minimum changes to the OP code.

Comment: @YakovGalka whoops, my bad, I didn't see the [tag:c] tag, thought it was a [tag:c++] question.